# Как сделать привязку кнопки- Enter на кнопку Button в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, label

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на клавиатуре, срабатывала кнопка из WPF. Вроде так можно было делать с помощью Label элемента управления.

Comment: В wpf на Enter (ввод) и на Esc можно подписаться стандартными методами, установив IsDefault или IsCancel в настройках кнопки. Может вам этого будет достаточно?

Comment: для этого случая да. Но может понадобиться забиндить и другие кнопки. В любом случае оставьте ответ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для клавиш Enter и Esc в WPF есть вспомогательные настройки у самой кнопки.

`IsDefault = "true"`
Установив данное значение в true - кнопка будет реагировать на нажатие клавиши **Enter**.

`IsCancel = "true"`
Установив данное значение в true - кнопка будет реагировать на нажатие клавиши **Esc**.

Однако!
В WPF принято использовать паттерн MVVM, а в нем не принято использовать Click события на кнопках или что то подобное, там принято использовать команды. Давайте попробуем реализовать пару команд с привязкой на заданные клавиши.

Для начала нам понадобится вспомогательный класс (я его возьму из [этого](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php) урока).

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Затем создадим ViewModel, в которой реализуем пару наших команд:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        HelloCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Hello());
        GoodbyeCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Goodbye());
    }

    public ICommand HelloCommand { get; }
    public ICommand GoodbyeCommand { get; }

    private void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Привет мир!");
    }

    private void Goodbye()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Мир, пока!");
    }
}
```

В окне, где наши кнопки зададим DataContext:

```
private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = MainViewModel;
}
```

Осталось чуть чуть поработать с XAML. Тут я лично буду задавать команды прямо окну с помощью InputBindings:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding HelloCommand}" Key="F1"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding GoodbyeCommand}" Key="F2"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Вот и все. Запускаем и видим, что при нажатие на F1 пишет в Debug окно "Привет мир!", а при нажатие на F2 увидим надпись "Мир, пока!".

---

Имея команду, мы ее смело можем прицепить и на кнопку:

```
<Button Command="{Binding HelloCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Кроме указанного в комментариях выше способа, можно сделать обработку события keydown на Вашем юзерконтроле. 
В бэккоде будет выглядеть как

```
KeyDown+=(sender,args) => { if (args.Key == Key.Enter) //вызов нужного метода
```

Так же можно воспользоваться keyBinding-ами. Их указывают в коллекции InputBindings окна или UserControl-а следующим образом:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Key="S"
               Command="{Binding SaveAsCommand}"/>

   <KeyBinding Key="S"
               Modifiers="Control+Shift" 
               Command="{Binding SaveAsCommand}">
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Этот способ чаще всего применим при работе с MVVM, когда в DataContext-е окна или UserControl-а прописаны соответствующие команды с обработчиками.