# Отловить нажатие на стрелки в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Каким образом можно отловить нажатие на стрелки при вводе текста в TextBox? Событие `KeyDown` не реагирует на их нажатие.

Comment: [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) вроде все просто.

Comment: @VladimirT: По вашей ссылке WinForms

Comment: @VladD а в чем принципиальная разница?

Comment: [PreviewTextInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput(v=vs.110).aspx) можно и так

Comment: Скорей всего как то [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827298/220553).

Comment: У меня `PreviewKeyDown` срабатывает