# Получение свойства элемента по клику

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `Grid`, на нем расположены в виде `DataGrid` информация для пользователя только стилизовано, использовать стандартный `datagrid` не захотел. Внутри ячеек грида `canvas` внутри `canvas` `textblock`. Проблема следующая, не могу сообразить как сделать, что бы по клику по гриду->строке получить информацию что в строке, что бы вывести полную информацию в отдельное окно. Как к строке прикрутить идентификатор, на коленке можно столбец с ИД из БД вывести, но как получить инфу из этого столбца подскажите какой нибудь вариант.

Comment: На сколько я понял, вам надо отработать клик по Grid, значит самый банальный вариант - обернуть все в button, изменить ему стиль и тогда будет вам клик. Более правильный вариант - использовать [InputBindings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827298/220553), установив что то вроде `<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" ... />` и передавать через команду нужные данные.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не совсем понимаю ваш совет. Мне необходимо идентифицировать строку в grid. Я из БД вычитываю и заполняю программно grid строками и контролами в этих строках. Мне по клику надо понять над какой строкой курсор и получить ИД этой строки.

Comment: `программно grid строками и контролами` - а вот это уже совершенно не правильный подход! Создание контролов из кода, это во первых издевательство над самим WPF, а во вторых, это уйма костылей и ненужного кода. Научитесь работать с привязками!! Вот самый [банальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799373/220553). И да, добавьте в вопрос ваши наработки!

Comment: У контролов есть свойство `Tag`, туда можно запоминать Id из БД. По событию клика по гриду, с помощью Linq запроса можно найти все контролы с этим Id, а далее считать из них значения. Но это все "детский сад - штаны на лямках". Изучите и используйте привязки, как вам посоветовал `EvgeniyZ`.