# Почему выкидывает исключение? Скопировал код с ответа

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Нужно привязать команду к клавише. Нашел [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827247/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-enter-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-button-%D0%B2-wpf-c) вопрос и ответ на него.

Копирую полностью XAML из ответа:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding HelloCommand}" Key="F1"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding GoodbyeCommand}" Key="F2"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Но при сборке приложение выбрасывается такое исключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему?

---

Полный XAML окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите полный  XAML окна (вырезав то, что не относится к вопросу).

Comment: А проект у вас на старом .NET я так понимаю? Если так, то вам придется писать [свои костыли](https://alvarodias.org/articles/going-the-inputbindings-way-part-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает из-за старой используемой версии .NET. В моем случае - v 3.5