# Как правильно повесить событие нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре?

Tags: c#, wpf

Почему не одно из событий не срабатывает по нажатии кнопки F5 ?

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка обновления
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnApdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    private void btnApdate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.F5)
        {
            btnApdate.Click += btnApdate_Click;
        }
    }
  
    private void btnApdate_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F5)
        {
            btnApdate.Click += btnApdate_Click;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вызвать обработчик клика из обработчика кнопок можно так `btnApdate_Click(sender, e);`, только выберите один из 2 обработчиков. Но что вам мешает про то вызвать `LoadData()`?

Comment: А вообще в WPF есть InputBindings и команды, обработчиками я не пользуюсь. Почитайте про MVVM, привязки данных и команды, вы узнаете, что в WPF то что вы делаете - неэффективно.

Comment: @aepot, сам метод пихал, тоже не работает. Они вообще не возникают эти событии

Comment: Недостаточно данных для определения причны проблемы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827298/220553